# How to overwrite one model property in ASP.Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model with say 10 properties. A, B, C and so on...

Property `A` is an array.

For each value in array I generate one  tag like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 row">
    @foreach (var item in Model.A)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-1 right-buffer">
            <a href="@item.Value"><i class="" aria-hidden="true">@item.Text</i></a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

When user clicks on some link I should redirect it to the same page, but with Some model property changed. For example:

Current url: `my/controller/someaction?name=Alex&age=20&from=fr&CurrentA=`
with model `?name=Alex&age=20&from=fr&CurrentA=`

If user clicks on `<a>` with text `foo` it should be redirected on `my/controller/someaction?name=Alex&age=20&from=fr&CurrentA=foo`

then is clicks on `<a>` with text `bar` and it should be now redirected on `my/controller/someaction?name=Alex&age=20&from=fr&CurrentA=bar`

So entire query string (except one parameter) should be preserved to send current model state to server while I want to set one value and redirect it to the same page but with new value.

Eventually, it should acts like `postback with one extra value setted to model`

Is it possible or I should use JS and perform everything myself?

Comment: Is this [ASP.NET Core MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc)?

Comment: @CodingGorilla Sure, see tags

Comment: Your tags are confusing, that's why I ask.  [asp.net], [asp.net-mvc] are still related to each other, but [asp.net-core] is completely un-related to either of the previous two.

Comment: @CodingGorilla asp.net core doesn't have WebForms which are completly abandonned, so ASP.Net core is synonim to `MVC6`. And Obsiosly, ASP.Net MVC6 is related to ASP.Net MVC and more generic ASP.Net itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually i solved it like this:

First, create hidden fields for every property in model:

```
<form asp-controller="search" asp-action="index" method="get" role="form" id="searchForm" asp-antiforgery="false">
    <input asp-for="SessionId" type="hidden" name="sessionId" value="@Model.SessionId" />
    <input asp-for="Quantity" type="hidden" name="quantity" value="@Model.Quantity"/>
    <input asp-for="SortField" type="hidden" name="sortField" value="@Model.SortField"/>
    <input asp-for="IsAscending" type="hidden" name="IsAscending" value="@Model.IsAscending" />
    <input asp-for="Offset" type="hidden" name="offset" value="0" />

    ...
</form>
```

Then, use JS to replace value in hidden field and then submit form. Values from inputs will be autimatically converter in query string, so everything works fine:

```
function sortDocuments(sortField) {
    var sField = document.getElementById('SortField');
    var isDescending = document.getElementById('IsAscending');
    if (sField.value === sortField) {
        if (isDescending.value.toUpperCase() === 'FALSE') {
            isDescending.value = 'TRUE';
        } else {
            sField.value = 'rank';
            isDescending.value = 'FALSE';
        }
    } else {
        sField.value = sortField;
        isDescending.value = 'FALSE';
    }
    document.getElementById('searchForm').submit();
}
```

Not very elegant, but it does its job.