# Modifying a model property of textarea in a View in ASP.NET Core

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, textarea

I have a View in ASP.NET Core application where I have a form:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="@Model.Property" class="col-md-2 control-label">Description</label>
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <textarea asp-for="@Model.Property" class="form-control" rows="10" data-val-maxlength-max="1000"></textarea>
      <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Property" class="text-danger" />
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to make textarea empty and Not to have the value from Model. I don't see any `value` property on this textarea.

Is it possible to have textarea mapped to `@Model.Property` but Not display it?

I'll be using this textarea for POST only and I don't want to display anything for GET. But I want to have other properties fetched so that's why I need the model in GET.

I also tried to change the Model property in controller before sending, but this model is a part of a DBSet and if I modify in controller then the DBSet gets affected.

Javascript is another option but I want to avoid that.
I had a look at [How to overwrite one model property in ASP.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917554/how-to-overwrite-one-model-property-in-asp-net-core) but this is not convincing.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to render the text area with empty value ? Why not set it to empty value in your GET action ?

Comment: The model that I am passing is a part of a DBSet. If I set model property to empty value in controller GET action method then that DBSet gets affected and I am using that DBSet on the View as well. So, there are 2 models on the view, One is DBSet<object> and other is object itself. That is why I am concentrating on changing that on textarea only.